# mysql workbench on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python3, mysql-workbench, sql

how to install MySQL workbench on Ubuntu 20.04?
MySQL workbench is not available on apt or the official website to MySQL

Comment: It can take some time for software to make available versions for new operating systems. You might try the 19.10 installer in their website.

Comment: Just to confirm - I installed 19.10 and it works fine but gives a warning.  You can upgrade to the full 20.04 version once it's released.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:
https://tutorialforlinux.com/tag/mysql-workbench-install-ubuntu/
Also:
[Mysql WorkBench not supporting with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230752/mysql-workbench-not-supporting-with-ubuntu-20-04-lts/1230755#1230755)